# How to merge the inner list of a 2d list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a 2d list like this:

```
[['dragon', 11], ['dragon', 111], ['stage_1', 1], ['stage_1', 2], ['stage_2', 10], ['stage_2', 12]].
```

I want it to look like this:

```
[['dragon', [11, 111]], ['stage_1', [1, 2]], ['stage_2', [10, 12]]]
```

Comment: Is it possible that your 2D list at the beginning is a list of tuples instead of the list of list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to use dictionary for your case like below

```py
d = { }
for key,value in ls:
    d[key] = d.get(key, []) + [value]

print(d)
```

you can use `d.items()` to get list of tuples if you need list

Answer (score 1):

With [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) object:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [['dragon', 11], ['dragon', 111], ['stage_1', 1], ['stage_1', 2], ['stage_2', 10], ['stage_2', 12]]
d = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in lst:
    d[k].append(v)
groups = list(map(list, d.items()))

print(groups)
```

The output:

```
[['dragon', [11, 111]], ['stage_1', [1, 2]], ['stage_2', [10, 12]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

For your 2d list structure you can use zip and list comprehension

```
lst = [['dragon', 11], ['dragon', 111], ['stage_1', 1], ['stage_1', 2], ['stage_2', 10], ['stage_2', 12]]

k, v = zip(*lst)
result = [[k[i], v[i:i+2]]  for i in range(0, len(k), 2)]
print(result)
```

Output

```
[['dragon', (11, 111)], ['stage_1', (1, 2)], ['stage_2', (10, 12)]]
```

**Performance Comparison**

*1. List Comprehension/Zip*

```
    k, v = zip(*lst)
    result = [[k[i], v[i:i+2]]  for i in range(0, len(k), 2)]

    100000 loops, best of 3: 3.72 µs per loop (using timeit)
```

*2. Dictionary*

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in lst:
    d[k].append(v)
groups = list(map(list, d.items()))

100000 loops, best of 3: 5.85 µs per loop (using timeit)
```

*Results*: List comprehension ~57% faster